# finding the pattern of given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know the starting numbers of a series ---

```
1 4 9 16 25 49 64 81 121 169 289 361 529 625 729 841 961 1024 1369 1681 1849 2209 2401 2809 
3481 3721..and so on
```

I want to find the next number in series but I can't understand the pattern.I know all these numbers are perfect squares.Help!

Comment: Take the square roots. Do you see a pattern now?

Comment: no thats wrong look carefully

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 11 13 17 19 23 25 27 29 31 32 37 41 43 47 49 53 59 61...

Comment: @SurayansTiwari what is wrong? If all the numbers are perfect squares, why don't you write the square roots out in the question so we can see if they have a pattern or not?

Comment: They are the squares of [OEIS A115975](http://oeis.org/A115975).

Comment: Looks like perfect squares of primes or of primes raised to power of other primes.

Comment: Has 256 been omitted in the series?

Answer (score 3):

I am normally against problems of the form $ a ,b ,c ,d \dots $ what is the next term. Notice that the number of sequences $a_1,a_2\dots $ of real numbers is the cardinality of the set $\mathbb R ^{\mathbb N}$.

The sequences that start in whichever configuration $a_1,a_2\dots a_n$ of terms you like is the cardinality of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N\setminus \{1,2,3\dots n\}}$ which has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R ^{\mathbb N}$, so knowing any number of the first terms won't help **at all**.

Even if you are told the terms $a_1,a_2\dots a_n$ are the values $f(1),f(2)\dots f(n)$ of a polynomial and we are told that all ther terms of the sequence obey the polynomial we can do nothing since we can build a poynomial $f'$ so that $f'(i)=a_i)$ fo all $1\leq i\leq n$ and so that $f'(n+1),f'(n+2)\dots f'(n+k)$ is whatever we like.

Notice however that if we are given $a_1,a_2\dots a_n$ and we are told that they obey a polynomial $f$ so that $f$ has degree $n-1$ then we can uniquely determine the function. Because given $n$ values there is a unique polynomial of degree $n-1$ which satisfies them.

In this case however we are told none of the information of either of the previous paragraphs. Therefore we cannot solve the problem, although if I was given this question in an exam I would definitely write it is the squares.

What I generally do when I am given these problems is try really hard for some time to find a pattern that is interesting or a well known sequence (like factorial, double factorial, look and see, etc.) If I can't do this I'll just write out the Lagrange polynomial and say that's the result.

---

I think this is a perfect example for such ambiguity:

When you take your sequence and square root everything you get (casually using Peterwhy's work) $1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 ,7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61$

Which are all prime powers. In fact you have all the prime powers up to $61$ where the exponent of the prime is $1,2,3$ or $5$ (Although this is true for the power $5$ all we have for sure is $2^5$) But even if we admit that the sequence is going to be that of terms of the form $p^k$ where $k$ belongs to a set of numbers containing $\{1,2,3,5\}$ I still have my doubts $k$ has to be a Fibonacci number. What if $k$ is a number with less than two divisors? I mean in this particular case there are a lot of properties the numbers $1,2,3,5$ have that $4$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

If I combine the comments, it's enumerating the numbers that can be written as 
$ p ^ {2i} $ where $p$ is prime and $i$ is a Fibonacci number (starting at 0).

And the next number that can be written like that would be $67^2$ I'd guess.

Comment: the condition is $i$ is a Fibonacci number.

Comment: Thanks achille, I modified my answer with your correction.

Answer (score 1):

**There are infinitely many options, but here is one of them...**

Let $P$ denote the set of all prime numbers and $1$, then each one of the numbers in your sequence is equal to an element in $P$ raised to the power of an element in $P$, and then raised to the power of $2$:

- $  1  = ( 1^1)^2$
- $  4  = ( 2^1)^2$
- $  9  = ( 3^1)^2$
- $ 16  = ( 2^2)^2$
- $ 25  = ( 5^1)^2$
- $ 49  = ( 7^1)^2$
- $ 64  = ( 2^3)^2$
- $ 81  = ( 3^2)^2$
- $ 121 = (11^1)^2$
- $ 169 = (13^1)^2$
- $ 289 = (17^1)^2$
- $ 361 = (19^1)^2$
- $ 529 = (23^1)^2$
- $ 625 = ( 5^2)^2$
- $ 729 = ( 3^3)^2$
- $ 841 = (29^1)^2$
- $ 961 = (31^1)^2$
- $1024 = ( 2^5)^2$
- $1369 = (37^1)^2$
- $1681 = (41^1)^2$
- $1849 = (43^1)^2$
- $2209 = (47^1)^2$
- $2401 = ( 7^2)^2$
- $2809 = (53^1)^2$
- $3481 = (59^1)^2$
- $3721 = (61^1)^2$

According to the definition above, the next one in line should be $4489 = (67^1)^2$.

Comment: Nice, another fancy one is the numbers of the form $p^{2k}$ where $k$ is a square-free number. An even fancier way to say this is $k$ is such that $\mu(k)\neq0$. Where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Comment: @ModdedBear: Thanks. There's something wrong with your LaTex formula on my browser.

Comment: @ModdedBear: Yep!